# Why can a client only receive one message in my Python chat program using sockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, pysimplegui

Python socket programming:A client can only receive one message in my chat program...

This is my Code:
I found it strange that after the window3 is displaying,you can send each other messages through ms!{target_id}|{message} and the server will send sm!{message} to the target.And the another person should get the message.
However,i found it strange that one person can only receive the message the other send once.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5eXD.png)
However the server is able to received all the messages and tried to send to the targets.However,one of them can only receive one message.

```
import os
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as gui
from rsa_controller import decryptwithPrivatekey, loadPublicKey, loadPrivateKey

id = 0
target_id = 0
prikey = None
window2_active = False  # Indicates whether the second window is open
window = None
window2 = None
window3 = None
exit_flag = False  # Indicates whether the program should exit
pubkey = None
prikey = None
target_pubkey = None
restart_thread = False

def popout(title):
    gui.popup(title)

def read_keys():
    global pubkey, prikey
    print("Opening key files" + os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\")
    pubkey = loadPublicKey(os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\public.pem")
    prikey = loadPrivateKey(os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\private.pem")

def recv_msg():
    global target_id, window2_active, exit_flag
    global target_pubkey
    from main import s
    while not exit_flag:
        try:
            print("BEAT")
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print("Received message:", decoded_data)
            if decoded_data == 'target_connected_Success':
                print("Received message:", decoded_data)
            elif decoded_data.startswith("!+@"):
                target_id = decoded_data[3:]
                if not window2_active:
                    window.write_event_value('open_window2', None)
            elif decoded_data == 'target_connect_denied':
                gui.popup('Connection request denied')
                exit_flag = True
            elif decoded_data.startswith("pu!"):
                parts = decoded_data.split("|")
                target_id = parts[0][3:]
                target_pubkey = parts[1]
                print("Received the public key of the other party:", target_pubkey)
                window.write_event_value('open_window3', None)
            elif decoded_data.startswith("sm!"):
                message = decoded_data[3:]
                window3['text_output'].print("{}:{}".format(target_id, message))
                continue
            else:
                msg_to_recv = decryptwithPrivateKey(decoded_data, prikey)
                print("Received message:", msg_to_recv)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception occurred while receiving message:", e)

def window2_event_handler(event):
    global window2_active, exit_flag
    global pubkey
    from main import s
    if event == 'denied':
        print("Connection denied")
        s.send('!x!{}'.format(target_id).encode('utf-8'))
        window2_active = False
        exit_flag = True
    elif event == 'accept':
        print("Confirm sharing my public key and establish connection")
        # Handle the logic for confirming the connection
        s.send("mp!{}|{}".format(target_id, pubkey).encode())
        window2_active = False
        exit_flag = True

def window2():
    from main import s
    global target_id, window2_active, exit_flag
    layout2 = [
        [gui.Text('Connecting with'), gui.Text(str(target_id), key='target_id'), gui.Text("...")],
        [gui.Button('Confirm sharing my public key and establish connection', key='accept', enable_events=True),
         gui.Button('Deny connection request', key='denied', enable_events=True)]
    ]
    window2_active = True
    window2 = gui.Window("Connection Request", layout2, finalize=True, no_titlebar=True)
    while True:
        event2, values2 = window2.read()
        if event2 == gui.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        window2_event_handler(event2)
        if exit_flag:
            break
    window2.close()

def window3():
    from main import s
    layout3 = [
        [gui.Multiline(size=(None, 10), key='text_output', disabled=True, autoscroll=True)],
        [gui.Input(size=(None, 1), key='text_input'), gui.Button('Send', key='send')]
    ]
    global window3
    window3 = gui.Window("Chat Window-{}".format(target_id), layout3, finalize=True)
    exit_flag_window3 = False  # Exit flag for window3
    while True:
        event3, values3 = window3.read()
        if event3 == gui.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            exit_flag_window3 = True  # Set the exit flag for window3 to True
            break  # Exit the event loop
        if event3 == 'send':
            message = values3['text_input']
            # Handle the sending logic
            window3['text_output'].print(f'You: {message}')
            s.send(f"ms!{target_id}|{message}".encode('utf-8'))
            window3['text_input'].update('')  # Clear the input field

    window3.close()

    # When window3 is closed, set the exit flag to True and wait for the event loop in the thread to exit
    exit_flag = True
    while threading.active_count() > 1:
        pass

def start_GUI_progress(id):
    from main import s
    global restart_thread
    read_keys()
    layout = [
        [gui.Text('Your ID'), gui.Text(id)],
        [gui.Text('Note: Please enter the target ID in the input box below and click the Connect button')],
        [gui.Input(key='target_id'), gui.Button('Connect', key='connect')]
    ]
    global window
    window = gui.Window("RSA Encrypted Instant Messaging", layout, finalize=True)
    host = "localhost"
    port = 23333
    s.connect((host, port))
    print(s.recv(1024))
    t_recv = threading.Thread(target=recv_msg)
    t_recv.start()
    # Send the ID
    s.send(b"__!" + str(id).encode('utf-8'))
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == gui.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        if not t_recv.is_alive():
            print("Thread DEAD!!")
        if event == 'connect':
            print("Client starts to attempt connection: {}".format(values['target_id']))
            # Construct the message to send
            message = "_!?{}".format(values['target_id'])
            # Send the message to the server
            s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            message = "mp!{}|{}".format(values['target_id'], pubkey)
            s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        elif event == 'open_window2':
            window2()
        elif event == 'open_window3':
            window3()
        elif event == gui.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
            break
    window.close()
```

Comment: `elif decoded_data == 'target_connect_denied':gui.popup('Connection request denied')`, you didn't update this `gui.popup` with `window.write_event_value`.

Comment: I dont think so, the problem is not on the side of denying the connection request, but happened in the situation that accepted the request..

Comment: Just tell you where I found issue, not debug all you code for your question here.

Answer (score 1):

This code suggests a misunderstanding of how the TCP protocol works:

```
data = s.recv(1024)
if not data:
   break
decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
print("Received message:", decoded_data)
```

In particular, `s.recv(1024)` doesn't receive "a message".

Rather, it receives the next *N* bytes of data from the socket (where N is the number of received bytes currently available for processing in the kernel's socket-buffer; in this case will be between 1 and 1024).

Because TCP does not provide *message framing*, that means that the number of bytes you receive may not correspond to the number of bytes previously sent by any particular `send()` call by the client.

For example, if the client sent three messages:

1. One 10-byte message
2. One 50-byte message
3. One 15-byte message

... then your first `recv()` call might return a buffer with anywhere between 1 and 75 bytes in it, and it is up to the receiving code to figure out how to handle it correctly if, for example, the first `recv()` call returned 34 bytes, then the second `recv()` call returned 16 bytes, and then the third `recv()` call returned the remaining 25 bytes.